# Datatable.Select with Like in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have a datatable where i am trying to do 
datatable.Select(Name Like '#%#') but getting error that invalid pattern(expecting result of a table with name col having #Mike#,#Brow#..).  Using escape sequense dint for all items dint work fine too. Many suggest to use Linq - but am new to it. How can i do this filter with Linq from this datatable.

This is a sample of what i was trying to do..

```
 Dim dtSamp As Data.DataTable
    dtSamp = New Data.DataTable
    dtSamp.Columns.Add("Name")
    dtSamp.Columns.Add("Marks")

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dtSamp.NewRow()
    dr.Item(0) = "AAA"
    dr.Item(1) = "50"
    dtSamp.Rows.Add(dr)
    dr = dtSamp.NewRow()
    dr.Item(0) = "#bbb#"
    dr.Item(1) = "60"
    dtSamp.Rows.Add(dr)
    dr = dtSamp.NewRow()
    dr.Item(0) = "ccc"
    dr.Item(1) = "44"
    dtSamp.Rows.Add(dr)

    Dim drResult As DataRow()
    drResult = dtSamp.Select("Name Like '#%#'")

    Dim dtOutPutTable As Data.DataTable
    dtOutPutTable = drResult.CopyToDataTable()
```

In the dtOutPutTable i was expecting 1 row ie, #bbb# in it.. but the Select function fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally LINQ queries works on data sources which implement the `IEnumerable<T>/ IQueryable<T> Interface`. But DataTable does not implement any of these. So we can not directly apply LINQ queries on a DataTable.

But DataTable class has an extension method called `AsEnumerable` which returns an `IEnumerable` collection of DataRow. So we can apply the `AsEnumerable` function on a DataTable and then play with some LINQ on the resulting collection.

```
var items=(from p in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 select new { ID= p.Field<int>("ID").
                              Name=p.Field<string>("Name")
                           }).ToList();
var filtered=items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Mike"));
```

**EDIT :** Here is the VB.NET Version ( Disclaimer: I am not a VB.NET guy. but i could build this code without any error)

```
Dim items = (From p In myDataTable.AsEnumerable() 
               Select New With {.ID = p.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                                .Name = p.Field(Of String)("Name")}).ToList()

Dim filtered = items.Where(Function(x) x.Name.Contains("Mike")).ToList()
```

Comment: VB.NET is tagged. Btw, in VB.NET `AsEnumerable` is not necessary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ah ! Let me come back with the VB.NET version.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I also understood why that Like was not working in Select statement., Like opearton canot have 2 conditions: start with and ends with. Can can one of both.
But it can be 2 conditions, one thats start with, and the other that ends with:
//VB:
Dim drResult As DataRow() = dtSamp.Select("Name Like '#%' AND Name Like '%#'")

Answer (score 1):

## VB

```
Private Function likes(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal column As String, ByVal value As String)
    Dim result = dt.Clone()
    For Each row As DataRow In From row1 As DataRow In dt.Rows Where (row1(column).Contains(value))
        result.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

## C#

```
private DataTable likes(ref DataTable dt, string column, string value)
 {
    DataTable result = dt.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow row in from row1 in dt.Rowswhere (row1(column).Contains(value))) {
        result.ImportRow(row);
    }
    return result;
 }
```